# Running Java (.jar) file on Apache Web Server

Tags: java, mysql, apache

We were told to develop a Students' Auditorium Management Software to effeciently manage the various shows conducted in the auditorium. It was told to us that the software should run on a high-end PC and free software such as Linux, mySQL, and Apache web server.
We have written the JAVA code for it including the GUI and used MySQL database to store the various details concerning tickets sold and show details. Now how should we run it on an Apache Server? So that, others can use the software.

Comment: You developed a whole solution _without at all thinking about how people can use it later_? Wow.

Comment: How did you make the GUI? Web servers run `war` files, not `jar` files and if you used `Swing` for the UI, it won't work.